# How do I check between 2 arrays of different objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check if a claim's items has assets in it and @item_assets basically gets all the items in the database that are classified as assets.

When doing the following:

```
>> @claim.items
=> [#<Item id: 8, name: "chair", amount: 10.0, gst: 0.7, override: false, item_category_id: 7, item_expense_id: 8, claim_id: 8, club_id: 71, created_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10", updated_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10">, #<Item id: 9, name: "soemthing", amount: 20.0, gst: 1.4, override: false, item_category_id: 7, item_expense_id: 7, claim_id: 8, club_id: 71, created_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10", updated_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10">]

>> @items_assets
=> [#<Item id: 8, name: "chair", amount: 10.0, gst: 0.7, override: false, item_category_id: 7, item_expense_id: 8, claim_id: 8, club_id: 71, created_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10", updated_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10">, #<Item id: 9, name: "soemthing", amount: 20.0, gst: 1.4, override: false, item_category_id: 7, item_expense_id: 7, claim_id: 8, club_id: 71, created_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10", updated_at: "2009-10-18 10:16:10">]

>> @claim.items.include? @items_assets
=> false
```

The result puzzles me. After investigation I realize that the items on both arrays are of different object even though they refer to the same id.

As such, it appears that include? can no longer work in this case.

Can someone suggest how else should I go about checking if a claim's items have assets in it?

```
Claim HM Items
Items BT Claim
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@claim.items.include? @items_assets
```

What you're asking here is "Does the array `@claim.items` contain an element equal to the `@item_assets` object?"

What you seem to want to ask is "Does the array `@claim.items` contain an element equal to any element in another array, `@item_assets`?"

`@claim.items != @claim.items - @item_assets` would return true if any element in `@item_assets` matched any element in `@claim.items`, but the performance of doing that will likely be terrible.

I would look at storing your `@item_assets` in a `Set`, assuming you really do want to yank them all into memory.  Then checks to see if your `@claim.items` elements appear in that `Set` will be much faster.